# Excel VBA for Uniques

Tags: excel, vba

I am looking to extract Unique in the format given on the right side. I found the VBA code on one of the forum site, but this one does not suit me. Is there a way to modify the code or write something better. I do have a formula, but formula is quite resource intensive and a very large excel loads very slowly.

```
Sub FindDistinctValues()
Dim LastRowFrom As Long
Dim LastRowTo As Long
Dim i As Long, j As Long
Dim temp As Integer
Dim found As Boolean
'determines the last row that contains data in column A
LastRowFrom = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
'Loop for each entry in column A
For i = 2 To LastRowFrom
'get the next value from column A
temp = Range("A" & i).Value

'Determine the last row with data in column B
LastRowTo = Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

'initialize j and found
j = 1
 found = False

     'Loop through "To List" until a match is found or the list has been    searched
      Do
      'check if the value exists in B column
      If temp = Range("B" & j).Value Then
     found = True
     End If
     'increment j
    j = j + 1
     Loop Until found Or j = LastRowTo + 1

    'if the value is not already in column B
    If Not found Then
   Range("B" & j).Value = temp
  End If
Next i
End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: I see the image was not posted so posting here, instead the code got messed up because of trying to load image. http://prntscr.com/cmwobj

Comment: Thanks Slai for the edit.

Comment: Do you need to do this dynamically on the list or is this a one off?

Comment: Are you looking for actual unique values or just where the values differ in Col D? 456 and 813 are not unique in that list, for example, whereas 243 and 213 are.

Comment: http://prntscr.com/cmy8at  

Sorry for the confusion. I should have used only one screenshot. I am looking to achieve this. Column D would be present, I need to achieve column E.  Since this is an ongoing excercise. I am trying to achieve using VBA. Currently I use formulae, which is very slow for very large data.

Comment: what is the Excel Formula that you use?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I didn't test it, but something like this:

```
Sub FindDistinctValues()
    Dim dict As Object, cell As Range
    Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

    For Each cell in Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Resize(, 1)
        If Not dict.Exists(cell & "")
            cell(, 2) = "Unique"
            dict.Add cell & "", 0
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```